# iOS dragging UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, drag

Ok, so I have always wondered how do I actually pick up an image view and drag it. I was planning when I drag an image view and when user places it to correct location it locks there. I really don't have idea how to do this and it has bothered me for sometime.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're one for reading, then check out the [`UIResponder` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html), and, in particular, `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved`.

Comment: So I should implement that method and track the coordinates of the touch and then move the imageView?

Comment: @Samuli: Yes... there are some good snippets out there (e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190935/iphone-sdktrouble-dragging-a-uiimageview)) that have examples, but basically you catch the event with `touchesBegan` and follow it with `touchesMoved` or `touchesEnded`.

Comment: Ok I think I actually get it now. I guessed it would be a lot harder :) Thanks!

Comment: @Samuli: Me, too. I just started working with these methods a couple of weeks ago, and I must say you can do some amazing stuff with very little code. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` if you don't want to subclass the view and handle touches yourself.

Create a pan recognizer in any class (e.g. view controller) and add it to your view:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                                 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[myDraggedView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

And then simply:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGRect frame = myDraggedView.frame;
    frame.origin = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:myDraggedView.superview];
    myDraggedView.frame = frame;
}
```

---

If you like Interface Builder as much as me you can also just drag a pan gesture recognizer over your image view, and then connect the recognizer to the `handlePanGesture:` that should be declared as an `IBAction` instead of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

I already worked with this, but the user can drag imageview freely with position that they want. and this is my custom class with swift

```
class DraggableImageView: UIImageView {
      var beganPoint: CGPoint? = nil
      var originCenter: CGPoint? = nil
      override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           if let position = touches.first?.location(in: superview){
                beganPoint = position
                originCenter = center
           }
      }
      override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      }
      override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
           if let position = touches.first?.location(in: superview){
                let newPosition = CGPoint(x: position.x - (beganPoint?.x)!, y: position.y - (beganPoint?.y)!)
                center = CGPoint(x: (originCenter?.x)! + newPosition.x, y: (originCenter?.y)! + newPosition.y)
           }
      }
}
```

Just user this custom class with your UIImageView